# Как настроить компиляцию scss в phpStorm только по сохранению файла?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

File Watcher phpStorm компилирует css из scss "на лету", после ввода каждого символа.

Как настроить watcher, чтобы css компилировался только по сохранению файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах File Watcher отключите опцию `Immediate file synchronization` - компилятор будет запускаться по нажатию <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> или при изменении фокуса (если включена опция `Save files on frame deactivation`, `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings`)

Comment: Огромное спасибо)